# page reloads in every link click instead of re-render matched component - react

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-props

I'm creating a website. I wanna use routes logic based on this project https://github.com/quintuslabs/fashion-cube. But when I click to my routes, page reloads, even if I used **Link** from react-router-dom instead of anchor tag. So, I have *StaffRoutes.js:*

```
var staffRoutes = [
    {
        path: "/members",
        name: "Members",
        component: MemberContainer,
        layout: BaseLayout,
        exact: true
    },
    {
        path: "/teachers",
        name: "Teachers",
        component: TeacherContainer,
        layout: BaseLayout,
        ...
    }]


export default staffRoutes
```

and I gathered all routes into one js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Redirect,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import Login from "../views/login";
import staffRoutes from "./StaffRoutes";

const PrivateRouter = ({ component, ...options }) => {
  const token = sessionStorage.getItem("token");
  const finalComponent =
    token ? (
      <Route {...options} component={component} />
    ) : (
      <Redirect to="/login" />
    );

  return finalComponent;
};

<Router>
    <Switch>
       {staffRoutes.map((route, key) => {
          return (
            <PrivateRouter
                path={route.path}
                key={key}
                exact={route.exact}
                component={props => {
                    return (
                      <route.layout {...props}>
                        <route.component {...props} />
                    </route.layout>
                    );
                  }}/>);
                   })}
                        
             <Route Redirect to="/login" exact component={Login} />
    </Switch>
 </Router>
```

My BaseLayout is:

```
<div className="main-content">
     <SidebarWrapper />
      <div className="home-section">
            <div className="home-content">
                 <Header />
             </div>
            <div>
                    {this.props.children}
             </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

I added every routes with **Link** in sidebar. My Sidebar is:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const Admin = () => {
  
  return (
    <>
      
          <ul className="sub-menu">
            
            <li>
              <Link to="/members">Members</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/teachers">Teachers</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/departments">Departments</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

When I click to links it reloads full page, instead of just re-rendering matched component. I think the problem is in

```
<route.layout {...props}>
    <route.component {...props} />
</route.layout>
```

But I can't figure it out. I want page re-renders only matched component, not reload full page. How to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

My project settings are: react: 17.0.2, react-router-dom: 5.3.0

Comment: Can you include all relevant code you are working with as part of a complete [mcve]? Where & how are you linking to pages in the app? Can you edit the existing snippets to include the imports/exports as well?

Comment: @DrewReese Hi Drew. thanks for attention. I added other information. I think I used <route.layout> in map, that's why it reloads every time. I put <route.layout> </route.layout> out of map and it changed routes perfectly without reloading, but components not showing in this condition.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would cause a full page reload. Can you clarify in more detail what exactly you mean here? Is the page really reloading or is *some* React component just remounting, or something else? Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?